# Are c-style arrays considered containers?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Are C-style arrays, such as `int holder[10]` considered a container? The reason why I ask is that it would make sense logically if they were but they do not appear on this [list of containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/)

Comment: Define containers

Comment: That link refers to the containers *library* - which is part of the C++ standard libraries

Comment: _They are implemented as class templates_ so plain arrays a not containers in that sense.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Why is this a language-lawyer question?

Comment: @PasserBy: Because it's apparently only about correct terminology.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I feel that it isn't obvious from what OP provided, and then the term _containers_ are used loosely even in the standard, making an answer based on the standard kinda weird, but is expected from a language-lawyer question

Comment: @PasserBy: The OP's comment below the other answer literally says *"it would be so logical if c-style arrays also are called containers"* - To me, that's really only about terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they aren't containers, because in the ISO C++ standard, the word "container" is only formally used for container classes in the standard library. The entire section on arrays, in contrast, does not use the word "container". See §11.3.4 in the [latest C++17 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf).

You can call arrays "compound types", "sequences of object" or "aggregates", but not "containers".

Answer (score 0):

They are not containers in the strict sense.

C++ `std::array` that is a container that adds a few things native arrays are missing (like being able to pass and return arrays by value).

Comment: What do you mean by containers?

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the description under the link you provided they are not. Read the link you provided yourself, the very first words:

> A container is a holder object that stores a collection of other
>   objects (its elements). They are implemented as class templates, which
>   allows a great flexibility in the types supported as elements.
>
> The container manages the storage space for its elements and provides
>   member functions to access them, either directly or through iterators
>   (reference objects with similar properties to pointers).
>
> Containers replicate structures very commonly used in programming:
>   dynamic arrays (vector), queues (queue), stacks (stack), heaps
>   (priority_queue), linked lists (list), trees (set), associative arrays
>   (map)...

Comment: I have, of course. The thing that just confuses is that it would be so logical if c-style arrays also are called containers since containers are objects that holds other objects.

Comment: You are trying to impose your own terminology here in a way.

The description clearly says `manages storages space` (i.e. allocator) and `provides member functions to access them` for example.
That's it. It is not what you wish it should/could be. It is what is officially described there in the very link that you sent; at least for the majority of the people. Having that said, SO is not a discussion site.

Comment: @step: It might be better to view arrays as a compiler-aided shortcut to defining several different variables. `int arr[3];` is really much more similar to `int x1; int x2; int x3;` than to a container.